# Trying to convert Date from SQL Server string to MySQL DATE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, mysql-workbench

I have a database on a local machine, this is based on SQL Server. I am migrating it to a web hosted MySQL database, using the migration tool in MySQL workbench. I am able to migrate the database, however the source DB uses a string to store the date in dd/mm/yyyy (not sure exactly why, I didn't write it) which means the target ends up column type string / varchar not date.

I have tried to convert in the column mapping section in the migration wizard using STR_TO_DATE (and I also set the column type from varchar to date)', to get it to the system default YYYY-MM-DD and then format back to dd/mm/yyyy. I need to do it when it migrates rather than once it reaches the target table, as I need to use these dates on a daily basis to determine new data, which will then move to a more permanent table.

I have several tables to do this in, but here is an example of the code for one table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `silverfe_extraction`.`BatchSummary` (
  `NetWeight` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `BatchID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `DrumNum` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `BeeKeeperID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
  `DrumDate` DATE NULL,
  `mafID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL)
$$
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('DrumDate', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') as 'DrumDateFormat' from 'silverfe_extraction'.'BatchSummary';
```

which results in:

Execute statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `silverfe_extraction`.`BatchSummary` (
      `NetWeight` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
      `BatchID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
      `DrumNum` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
      `BeeKeeperID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
      `DrumDate` DATE NULL,
      `mafID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL)
    $$
     SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('DrumDate', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'DrumDateFormat' FROM 'silverfe_extraction'.'BatchSummary'
```

> WARNING: ERROR executing `` 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `silverfe_extraction`.`BatchSummary` (
>     `NetWeight` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
>     `BatchID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
>     `DrumNum` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
>     `BeeKeeperID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL,
>     `DrumDate` DATE NULL,
>     `mafID` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL)
>   $$
>    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('DrumDate', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') as 'DrumDateFormat' from 'silverfe_extraction'.'BatchSummary'' ``
>
> You have an ERROR IN your SQL syntax; CHECK the manual that corresponds TO your MySQL SERVER VERSION FOR the RIGHT syntax TO USE near `'$$
>    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('DrumDate', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y') as 'Drum'` at line 8.
>   SQL Error: 1064

I used the delimiter as it wouldn't recognise that the table existed. Help appreciated.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` takes a `str` and makes a `date`. `DrumDate` is already a `date`. Try `;` as a delimiter and not `$$`

Comment: And use backtick as fieldnames and tablenames quote char instead of single quote (or use none until this needed really) -  your `'DrumDate'` is a string literal, not a field name.

Comment: Thanks Akina - amateur hour you can tell! I actually just discovered this using a syntax checker :) thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Drum date is coming as a string - this is how it is saved in MSSQL in the source database and also how it is migrated to the MYSQL target database. Therefore I am trying to convert it from a string to the mysql recognised date, and from there re-format it.

Comment: DrumDate is in fact the name of the column, so is it ok to leave without quote characters?

Comment: Note, DrumDate is only a DATE because I manually changed the column type from VARCHAR (50). Should I have left it as the original column type?